# Get all Attribute Sets in Static Block

Tags: magento-1.9, attribute-set

Display all atrribute sets as a dropdown list in a static block.Then selecting one, display all the products from corresponding attribute set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all attribute set list using below code.

```
$entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection');
$attributeSetCollection->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
foreach ($attributeSetCollection as $attributeSet) {
    $name = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName(); 
    $attributeSetId = $attributeSet->getId();
}
```

You can get Products from attribute set id as below

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);

foreach ($products as $child) {
    echo $child->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to add search by attribute set to advanced search form.

in app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml

You can get the dropdown using below code in the form

```
<li>
<?php
$entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
?>

<label for="attribute_set_search_field">Search :</label>
<select name="attributeset" id="attribute_set_search_field">
  <option value="">-- Any --</option>
<?php foreach($collection as $coll): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $coll->getAttributeSetId();?>"><?php echo $coll->getAttributeSetName();?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</li>
```

Then in app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Advanced.php

replace the getSearchCriterias() function with the code below

```
public function getSearchCriterias(){
    $search = $this->_searchCriterias;

    /* display attribute set filtering criteria */

    if(isset($_GET['attributeset']) && is_numeric($_GET['attributeset'])) {
        $entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
        $attributeSetId = $_GET['attributeset'];
        $myattriset = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType)
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId)
            ->getFirstItem();
        $search[] = array('name'=>'Attribute set','value'=>$myattriset->getAttributeSetName());
    }

    return $search;
}
```

then replace the next function, getProductCollection(), with:

```
public function getProductCollection(){
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $collection = $this->_engine->getAdvancedResultCollection();
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        if (!$collection) {
            return $collection;
        }
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;

    /* include attribute set filtering */
        if(isset($_GET['attributeset']) && is_numeric($_GET['attributeset']))
            $this->_productCollection
                 ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$_GET['attributeset']);

    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Then in function addFilters($values) you can see following code

```
if ($allConditions) {
        $this->getProductCollection()->addFieldsToFilter($allConditions);
    } else if (!count($filteredAttributes)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('You have to specify at least one search term'));
    }
```

Replace with

```
if (($allConditions) || (isset($values['attributeset']) && is_numeric($values['attributeset']))) {
        $this->getProductCollection()->addFieldsToFilter($allConditions);
    } else if (!count($filteredAttributes)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('You have to specify at least one search term'));
    }
```

Now you can search product by attribute set in your advanced search form

You can also use the code below in any template file

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result') ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">

<?php
$entityType = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityType);
?>

<label for="attribute_set_search_field">Search :</label>
<select name="attributeset" id="attribute_set_search_field">
  <option value="">-- Any --</option>
<?php foreach($collection as $coll): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $coll->getAttributeSetId();?>"><?php echo $coll->getAttributeSetName();?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

</form>
```

You can also duplicate your advanced search form to make changes there, following this tutorial http://inchoo.net/magento/advanced-search-in-magento-and-how-to-use-it-in-your-own-way/

Thanks to this tutorial that gives the same answer for adding search by category https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/How+to+Add+Search+By+Category+to+Advanced+Search